# React-Native Items not stretching when used with flexWrap

Tags: css, react-native

I have a view similar to the following

```
<View style={{
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 20,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }}>
    <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        minHeight: 200,
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    }} />
    <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        minHeight: 200,
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
    }} />
</View>
```

The above layout works on https://yogalayout.com. Two rectangles which get wrapped if in landscape mode. (When height and width are interchanged in yogalayout. 500x300 or 300x500)

But when used in react-native the child view takes only the width of the content in it. Does not get the default `alignItems: 'stretch'` behavior.

If I add `alignContent: 'stretch'` the child views are stretched to full width in portrait mode. But, in landscape mode, the views will not be wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to use `flexBasis` instead of `minHeight` for child views along with `alignContent: 'stretch'` in the parent view.